# How to fix Google Chrome browser to fetch all the files from server?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have webapp running and there is a specific scenario where I need to reload all the files from the server (e.g. HTML, CSS and JS) ignoring the cache from the browser

**The Problem with chrome is its always loading from memory cache.**

Currently in my javascript using below code to refresh the code from server

**location.reload(true);**

This is perfectly working in Firefox, but from chrome its always loading from cache. Tried to set meta in HTML header and http response as well, but no luck

Expected Outcome: it should reload all the files from server

Comment: [Java != JavaScript](http://javascriptisnotjava.com).

Comment: is this another example of "google knows best" going horribly wrong?